# Express doesn't set a cookie

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

I have problem with setting a cookies via express. I'm using `Este.js dev stack` and I try to set a cookie in API auth `/login` route. Here is the code that I use in [`/api/v1/auth/login`](https://github.com/este/este/blob/master/src/server/api/auth.js) route

```
res.cookie('token', jwt.token, {expires: new Date(Date.now() + 9999999)});
res.status(200).send({user, token: jwt.token});
```

In `src/server/main.js` I have registered `cookie-parser` as first middleware

```
app.use(cookieParser());
```

The response header for `/api/v1/auth/login` route contains

```
Set-Cookie:token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJ..
```

**but the cookie isn't saved in browser** (`document.cookie` is empty, also `Resources - Cookies` tab in develepoers tools is empty) :(

**EDIT:**
I'm found that when I call this in `/api/v1/auth/login` (without call `res.send` or `res.json`)

`res.cookie('token', jwt.token, {expires: new Date(Date.now() + 9999999), httpOnly: false});`
`next();`

**then the cookie is set** AND response header has set `X-Powered-By:Este.js` ... this sets `esteMiddleware` in [expres frontend rendering part](https://github.com/este/este/blob/master/src/server/frontend/index.js).

When I use `res.send`

```
res.cookie('token', jwt.token, {expires: new Date(Date.now() + 9999999), httpOnly: false}).send({user, token: jwt.token});`
next();
```

then I get error `Can't set headers after they are sent.` because `send` method is used, so frontend render throw this error.

But I have to send a data from API, so how I can deal with this?

Comment: Do you realize that it's `document.cookie`, not `document.cookies`?  And, when you look for the cookies are you in a page with the exact same domain as `/api/v1/auth/login` was sent to?

Comment: Sorry for typo error, sure `document.cookie` is empty (edited). Yes, it's same domain everything is at `http://localhost:8000/`

Comment: @Mira Is the cookie available server-side in later requests – [`req.cookies.token`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.cookies)? What other options are given in the `Set-Cookie` header after the value?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski  `req.cookies` is empty object `{}` ... here is complete `Set-Cookie` `Set-Cookie:token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJfaWQiOiJ2VXNlci8xNDA5Mjc0OTYwODc4NCIsImlhdCI6MTQ2MTUxNDc4MCwiZXhwIjoxNDYyOTc2Mjk1Njc2fQ.G46f18mjZgvIQwCw-uUr6wuF8mkoH-SgzNW5UyyTCUbI6PDiDhkZbBMkvIzUofRfRqNnxKmKWzyhQ79zjClocdzB6JH2niDLFMAMSxE36zqUOcc5C0z6FY5gu9z3dyT0zqnvTxR1DX1mijl-r-K_UOOc5Pf2D-8dwiN-V3ELTIObWnuP65KLDgR6kqRvCXU5_DGamroIlwiAfGEiPU-NeIDWK0yJTB1NNpBLBh9SuEtq38oSZ9n6pRCcrBGfCYuErkDvgT5p_-GWk8_IWr0U3UsXtsE89F5lVdkSRJpdQDH-psDP7n8jjCDd-hrBusIoRtl_JjEtU5wV4cmcaEakPQ; Path=/; HttpOnly`

Comment: @JonathanLonowski As I said all requests are from same domain. I also previously tried to change `httpOnly: false` in  `res.cookies` options but without any effect :(

Comment: Main problem is that the cookie isn't saved in browser at all .

Comment: @Mira Could there be any other code, perhaps a module your application is using, which could be setting the cookie? As well as including `HttpOnly` when you didn't set it, the header doesn't mention the `Expires` option to match your snippet.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski No, there is no other server part where I set a cookie. Sorry I send you wrong Set-cookie (for other code snippet, I still trying to solve it) here is Set-cookie for this code `res.cookie('token', jwt.token, {expires: new Date(Date.now() + 9999999), httpOnly: false}).send({user, token: jwt.token}).end();`   `Set-Cookie:token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJ.....; Path=/; Expires=Sun, 24 Apr 2016 21:36:05 GMT`

Comment: Do you see the `Set-Cookie` header in the response from the server?

Comment: @Mira Had same issue, but actually https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials is what you need to have cookies back to server.

Answer (score 128):

I had the same issue. The server response comes with cookie set:

```
Set-Cookie:my_cookie=HelloWorld; Path=/; Expires=Wed, 15 Mar 2017 15:59:59 GMT
```

But the cookie was not saved by a browser.

This is how I solved it.

I use `fetch` in a client-side code. If you do not specify `credentials: 'include'`  in `fetch` options, cookies are neither sent to server nor saved by a browser, although the server response sets cookies.

Example:

```
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');

return fetch('/your/server_endpoint', {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'same-origin',
    redirect: 'follow',
    credentials: 'include', // Don't forget to specify this if you need cookies
    headers: headers,
    body: JSON.stringify({
        first_name: 'John',
        last_name: 'Doe'
    })
})
```

Comment: Wow. The `credentials` part really was the problem. I was banging my head all day. Thanks! Can you please explain why that is needed?

Comment: `credentials: 'include'` was the answer. I also had to properly configure CORS on my backend, and it worked nicely. Thanks!!!

Comment: Just a note that this isn't as much as "express" not setting the cookie but rather browser not allowing cookie unless you explicitly tell it to with "credentials" field. Do note that `credentials: 'include'` will set cookie from any domain while `credentials:'same-site'` will only set cookie from the same domain as the client. [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Sending_a_request_with_credentials_included)

Comment: Its actually `credentials: "same-origin"` according to MDN docs for fetch API. Read more : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: Yes , I was also stuck with axios . Then after wasting lot of time I removed all my code I started with fetch .and finally it works.

Answer (score 24):

Struggling with this for a 3h, and finally realized, with `axios`, I should set `withCredentials` to `true`, even though I am only receiving cookies.

`axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;`

Answer (score 16):

I work with express 4 and node 7.4 and Angular, I had the same problem this helped me:

a) server side: in file app.js I give headers to all responses like:

```
 app.use(function(req, res, next) {  
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
      next();
 });
```

**This must have before all routers**.
I saw a lot of added this header:

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","*");
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
```

but I don't need that.

b) when you define cookie you need to add `httpOnly: false`, like:

```
res.cookie( key, value,{ maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 10, httpOnly: false });
```

c) client side: in send ajax you need to add: `withCredentials: true,` like:

```
$http({
     method: 'POST',
     url: 'url', 
     withCredentials: true,
     data : {}
   }).then(function(response){
        // do something  
   }, function (response) {
        // do something else
   });
```

Answer (score 10):

I was also going through the same issue.

Did code changes at two place :

1. At client side :

```
   const apiData = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/user/login", 
{
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(this.state),
        credentials: "include", // added this part
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      })
```

2. And at back end:

```
   const corsOptions = {
    origin: true, //included origin as true
    credentials: true, //included credentials as true
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue with cross origin requests, here is how I fixed it. You need to specifically tell browser to allow credentials. With axios, you can specify it to allow credentials on every request like
`axios.defaults.withCredentials = true`
however this will be blocked by CORS policy and you need to specify credentials is true on your api like

```
const corsOptions = {
    credentials: true,
    ///..other options
  };

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Update: this only work on localhost
For detail answer on issues in production environment, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63978697/12330711)

Answer (score 5):

There's a few issues:

- a cookie that isn't explicitly set with `httpOnly : false` will *not* be accessible through `document.cookie` in the browser. It will still be sent with HTTP requests, and if you check your browsers' dev tools you will most likely find the cookie there (in Chrome they can be found in the *Resources* tab of the dev tools);
- the `next()` that you're calling should only be used if you want to defer sending back a response to some other part of your application, which—judging by your code—is not what you want.

So, it seems to me that this should solve your problems:

```
res.cookie('token', jwt.token, {
  expires  : new Date(Date.now() + 9999999),
  httpOnly : false
});
res.status(200).send({ user, token: jwt.token });
```

As a side note: there's a reason for `httpOnly` defaulting to `true` (to prevent malicious XSS scripts from accessing session cookies and the like). If you don't have a very good reason to be able to access the cookie through client-side JS, don't set it to `false`.

Comment: I already tried to use this code (see first post) but _Resources - Cookie_ tab of the dev tools is still empty. I don't know why cookie isn't saved in browser :(

Answer (score 3):

Double check the size of your cookie.

For me, the way I was generating an auth token to store in my cookie, was causing the size of the cookie to increase with subsequent login attempts, eventually causing the browser to not set the cookie because it's too big.

[Browser cookie size cheat sheet](http://browsercookielimits.squawky.net/)

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem in Angular application. The cookies was not set in browser although I used

```
res.cookie("auth", token, {
  httpOnly: true,
  sameSite: true,
  signed: true,
  maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
});
```

To solve this issue, I added `app.use(cors({ origin:true, credentials:true }));` in `app.js` file of server side

And in my order service of Angular client side, I added `{withCredentials: true}` as a second parameter when http methods are called like following the code

```
getMyOrders() {
return this.http
  .get<IOrderResponse[]>(this.SERVER_URL + '/orders/user/my-orders', {withCredentials: true})
  .toPromise();}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am late to the party but nothing fixed it for me. This is what I was missing (and yeah, it's stupid):

I had to add `res.send()` after `res.cookie()` - so apperently sending a cookie is not enough to send a response to the browser.

```js
res.cookie("testcookie", "text", cookieOptions);
res.send();
```

Answer (score 1):

A cookie can't be set if the client and server are on different domains. Different sub-domains is doable but not different domains and not different ports.

If using Angular as your frontend you can simply send all requests to the same domain as your Angular app (so the app is sending all API requests to itself) and stick an /api/ in every HTTP API request URL - usually configured in your environment.ts file:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  httpPhp: 'http://localhost:4200/api'
}
```

Then all HTTP requests will use `environment.httpPhp + '/rest/of/path'`

Then you can proxy those requests by creating proxy.conf.json as follows:

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:5200",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": ""
    }
  }
}
```

Then add this to ng serve:

```
ng serve -o --proxy-config proxy.conf.json
```

Then restart your app and it should all work, assuming that your server is actually using Set-Cookie in the HTTP response headers. (Note, on a diff domain you won't even see the Set-Cookie response header, even if the server is configured correctly).

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem to set "httpOnly" to true in a cookie.

I am using "request-promise" for requests and the client is a  "React" app, but the technology doesn't matter. The request is:

```
    var options = {
        uri: 'http://localhost:4000/some-route',
        method: 'POST',
        withCredentials: true
    }

    request(options)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response)
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err)
        });
```

The response on the node.js (express) server is:

```
   var token=JSON.stringify({
  "token":"some token content"
});
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "http://127.0.0.1:3000");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
res.header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials',true);
var date = new Date();
var tokenExpire = date.setTime(date.getTime() + (360 * 1000));
res.status(201)
   .cookie('token', token, { maxAge: tokenExpire, httpOnly: true })
   .send();
```

The client make a request, the server set the cookie , the browser (client) receive it (you can see it in "Application tab on the dev tools") and then I again launch a request to the server and the cookie is located in the request: "req.headers.cookie" so accessible by the server for verifying.

Answer (score 1):

vue axios + node express 2023

server.ts (backend)

```
const corsOptions = {
  origin:'your_domain',
  credentials: true,
  optionSuccessStatus: 200,
}
```

auth.ts (backend)

```
res.cookie('token', JSON.stringify(jwtToken), {
  secure: true,
  httpOnly: true,
  expires: dayjs().add(30, "days").toDate(),
  sameSite: 'none'
```

})

authService.ts (frontend)

```
export class AuthService {
  INSTANCE = axios.create({
    withCredentials: true,
    baseURL: 'your_base_url'
  })

  public Login = async (value: any): Promise<void> => {
    try {
      await this.INSTANCE.post('login', { data: value })

      console.log('success')
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
  }
}
```

it works for me, the cookie is set, it is visible from fn+F12 / Application / Cookies and it is inaccessible with javascript and the document.cookie function. [Screenshot Cookies Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKdFt.png)

Answer (score 1):

I fix this issue by setting withCredentials to true on the client side fetch API request

```
const options = {
            url: '/your-url',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            credentials: 'include', 
            withCredentials: true, // You need to specify this if you are using cookies
            data: {
                yourData: yourDataValue
            }
          };
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the main features is to set header correctly.

For nginx:

add-header Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'domain.com';

add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';

Add this to your web server.

Then form cookie like this:

```
"cookie": {
        "secure": true, 
        "path": "/", 
        "httpOnly": true, 
        "hostOnly": true, 
        "sameSite": false, 
        "domain" : "domain.com"
    }
```

The best approach to get cookie from express is to use cookie-parser.

Answer (score 0):

Most of these answers provided are corrections, but either of the configuration you made, cookies won't easily be set from different domain. In this answer am assuming that you are still in local development.

To set a cookie, you can easily use any of the above configurations or

```
  res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', ['foo=bar', 'bar=baz']); // setting multiple  cookies or 
          res.cookie('token', { maxAge: 5666666, httpOnly: true })
```

Both of the will set your cookie while to accessing your cookie from incoming request req.headers.
In my case, my cookie were not setting because my server was running on http://localhost:7000/ while the frontend was running on http://127.0.0.1:3000/  so the simple fix was made by making the frontend run on http://localhost:3000 instead.

Answer (score 0):

I struggle with it a lot so follow below solution to get through this

1 check  if you are getting token with response with postmen in my case i was getting token in postmen but it wasn't being saved in cookies.

I was using a custom publicRequest which looks like below

```js
  try {
    const response = await publicRequest.post("/auth/login", user, {withCredentials: true});
    dispatch(loginSuccess(response.data));
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch(loginFail());
    dispatch(reset());
  }
```

I was using this method in other file to handle login

I added {withCredentials: true} in both methods as option and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to combine:

- including credentials on the request with, for example `withCredentials: true` when using axios.
- including credentials on the api with, for example `credentials: true` when using `cors()` mw.
- including the origin of your request on the api, for example `origin: http://localhost:3000` when using `cors()` mw.

Answer (score 0):

In 2023,
I solved this issue by adding small things in the code in my node-react app.

a) react code. in axios request. add `withCredentials : true`

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    try {
      
      e.preventDefault() ;
      const response = await axios.post(`${API_URLS.LOGIN}`,formData, { withCredentials: true }) ;
      // other code
      navigate("/") ; // to home page

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

b)in node, in main file like app.js, add corsOptions,

```
const corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:3000", // to allow requests from client
  credentials: true,
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Fetch which you are using to post to Backend you will have to add a column i.e credentials:'include', like this:-

```
method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    },
    credentials: "include",
    body: JSON.stringify({ parameters }),
```

also in the Backend specify the URL. Let's say the frontend is running on localhost:3000 so specify it in CORS origin. like this:-

```
cors({
origin: "http://localhost:3000",
credentials: true,
 })
```

and then to set the cookie:-

```
 res.cookie("token", token, {
          httpOnly: true,
          expires: new Date(Date.now() + 99* 99* 99 * 60000),
        });
```

This should solve the problem, to view if the cookie is set or not go to Developer console -> applications -> cookies

Answer (score -1):

```html
app.post('/api/user/login',(req,res)=>{

    User.findOne({'email':req.body.email},(err,user)=>{
        if(!user) res.json({message: 'Auth failed, user not found'})
        
        user.comparePassword(req.body.password,(err,isMatch)=>{
            if(err) throw err;
            if(!isMatch) return res.status(400).json({
                message:'Wrong password'
            });
            user.generateToken((err,user)=>{
                if(err) return res.status(400).send(err);
                res.cookie('auth',user.token).send('ok')
            })
        }) 
    })
});
```

### response

#### res.cookie('auth',user.token).send('ok')

server gives response ok but the cookie is not stored in the browser

### Solution :

Add Postman Interceptor Extension to chrome which allows postman to store cookie in browser and get back useing requests.