# Cookies are being sent but chrome doesn't set them

Tags: reactjs, express, cookies, localhost

I saw many similar questions and played with many combinations but nothing works.
I specify that it's all on localhost.

```
    regUser = () => {
    var username = getE("username-input").value;
    var email = getE("email-input").value;
    var password = getE("password-input").value;
    axios({
        url: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + "register",
        method: "post",
        data: {
            username, email, password
        },
        withCredentials: true
    }).then(res => {
        if(res.data.regSuccess) {
            // Registration successful
            this.setState({
                regSuccess: true,
                regTextHidden: false,
                regText: "Registration Successful! An e-mail was sent to the specified e-mail address with confirmation information! You will be redirected to the Login page..."
            }, ()=>{
                setTimeout(
                    ()=>{window.location.href=("/login")}, 5000
                    )
            })
        } else {
            this.setState({
                regSuccess: false,
                regTextHidden: false,
                regText: "An error occured. Please try again later!"
            })
        }
    })
}
```

Backend code:

```
            f.checkPassword(userData, function(result) {
            if(!result.correct) {
                // Wrong password
                res.send({found: true, correct: false})
                
            } else {
                // Proceed with authentication
                var token = f.genToken(userData.user);
                res.header("OPTIONS", 'true')
                res.cookie("access-token", token.token, {httpOnly: true, sameSite: "none", maxAge: "100000", secure: false});
                res.send({found: true, correct: true})
            }
        })
```

No matter what cookie settings I use, they are being sent, the "Set-Cookie" header is present but no cookie is set.

[image: The cookie is being sent]

[image: Chrome did not set it]

I've played with every option for like 2 days but it just doesn't work. Any advice?

Comment: Possible answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36824106/express-doesnt-set-a-cookie

Comment: Tried all answers but none of them worked :(

Comment: Edit: I'm tired, I tried to edit a different request in react... It works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was stuck on this for a while too. A couple things fixed it for me:

in the frontend in the axios call (which I see you've done), use:

```
withCredentials: true
```

Then in the backend in express, use npm package `cors`, with the following:

```
const app = express();
app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: 'http://localhost:3000' }));
```

Or use whatever your url origin is. Hope this works for you.

Comment: Yeah I had to play like with legos with the credentials and cors combos I got it figured out eventually sorry for the late answer I don't really use stack I'm still learning and I'm just exercising...