# couldn't set cookie from frontend react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, cookies

I have a backend node server, that has two apis: to set and to get cookies.

**Backend code to set and get cookies:**

Server : localhost:4001

```
router.get("/addCartToCookie", function(req, res){
  let options = {
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 15,
    httpOnly: true,
  };

  let cartData = {
    name: req.body.name,
    slug: req.body.slug,
    productPictures: req.body.productPictures,
    price: req.body.price,
    description: req.body.description,
    quantity: req.body.quantity,
  };

  // Set cookie
  res.cookie("cartName", cartData, options); // options is optional
  res.send("Cart Added to Cookie");
});

//To get the cookie
router.get("/getCartFromCookie",function(req, res){
  res.send(req.cookies);
  console.log(req.cookies["cartName"]);
});
```

Frontend react code to call the api on button click:

Client: localhost:3001

```
  const addToCartCookie = () => {
    console.log("Calling add to cart cookie");
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:4001/api/addCartToCookie", {
        name: product.name,
        slug: product.slug,
        productPictures: product.productPictures[0].img,
        description: "sabdsjbfjsd",
        price: product.storePrice,
        quantity: itemCount,
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

OnClick calls the above api,

```
      <Button
        type="primary"
        onClick={() => {
          addToCartCookie();
        }}
      >
        ADD TO CART
      </Button>
```

It doesn't set a cookie in the client browser upon the button click. While checking the network tab, the api is called fine but the only problem is that it is not setting the cookie on to client side.

Comment: Maybe this will solve your problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36824106/express-doesnt-set-a-cookie

Comment: @joinplastic tried setting http to false and withCredentials to true and also added headers but still its not working

Answer (score 0):

On the front end, set the **allow-credentials** header to true, and on the api, set **Origin-Allow-Credentials** header to true, save then restart your server. And then after saving the front-end, left click on the browser reload icon on your website, **"click on hard reload and delete cache".** Then retry.