# Cookies Not Store in browser

Tags: node.js, cookies, server, next.js

I tried everything to save the cookies through the server but it didn't happen

When I am storing the cookie in the index.js file through routes it stores the cookie in the browser

but when I try within the Auth Controller is not working

And Auth Controller is calling in the routes folder called authRouter

where I am only defining the endpoints and calling the middleware in the routes.js file

---

```
                                     INDEX.js
```

---

```
import "dotenv/config";
import "./helpers/init_mongodb.js";

import express from 'express';
import morgan from 'morgan';
import createError from "http-errors";
import cors from "cors";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";


import authRouter from "./routes/Auth.route.js";

(async () => {


  const app = express();

  app.use(morgan("dev"));

   app.use(express.json());

   app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

   app.use(cookieParser());

   app.use(cors());



   app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
      next();
    })

    app.get("/", (req, res) => {
       res.send("WELCOME TO CODERS PARK");
    });

   app.use("/auth", authRouter);


   // HTTP ERRORS

    app.use((req, res, next) => {
       next(createError(404));
   });

   app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
       res.locals.message = err.message;
       res.locals.error = req.app.get("env") === "development" ? err : {};

       res.status(err.status || 500);
       res.json({
           error: {
              message: err.message
           }
       });
   });

   app.listen(process.env.PORT || 4000, () => {
      console.log(`Server is running on port ${process.env.PORT || 4000}`);
   });
}
)();
```

---

```
                                  AUTHCONTROLLER.js
```

---

```
import User from "../models/User.model.js";
import { generateToken } from "../helpers/jwt_helper.js";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";

 // handle Error
 const handleError = (err) => {
console.log(err.message, err.code);
let errors = { name: '', email: '', password: '' };

// not enter name
if (err.message === "Please Enter Your Name") {
    errors.name = "Please Enter Your Name";
}


// not enter both email and password
if (err.message === "Please Enter Your Email and Password") {
    errors.email = "Please Enter Your Email";
    errors.password = "Please Enter Your Password";
}


// incorrect email
if (err.message === 'incorrect email' || err.message === 'Incorrect Email') {
    errors.email = 'That email is not registered';
}

// incorrect password
if (err.message === 'incorrect password' || err.message === 'Incorrect Password') {
    errors.password = 'That password is incorrect';
}

// duplicate error code
if (err.code === 11000 || err.code === 11001) {
    errors.email = 'That email is already registered';
    return errors;
}

// validation errors
if (err.message?.includes('user validation failed') || err.message?.includes('User validation failed')) {
    Object.values(err.errors).forEach(({ properties }) => {
        errors[properties.path] = properties.message;
    });
  }

  return errors;
}

const register = async (req, res, next) => {

  const { firstName, lastName, email, password } = req.body;

   console.log(req.body);

   const name = firstName + " " + lastName;

    try {

      if (!firstName || !lastName || firstName === "" || lastName === "") {
          throw new Error("Please Enter Your Name");
       }

       const user = await User.create({ name, email, password });

       res.status(201).json({ user: user.uid });

  }   catch (err) {
       res.status(500).send(handleError(err));
   }
  }

  const login = async (req, res, next) => {

const { email, password } = req.body;

console.log(email, password);

if (!email || !password || email === "" || password === "") {
    res.status(500).send(handleError("Please Enter Your Email and Password"));
    return;
}

try {

    const user = await User.findOne({ email });

    if (user) {
        const auth = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
        if (auth) {
            const token = generateToken(user.uid);

            console.log(token)

            res.cookie('jwt', token, { maxAge: 10000000 * 365, httpOnly: true }); // 1 year

            res.status(200).json({ user: user.uid });
            return;
        }
         throw Error('incorrect password');

       } else {
          throw Error('incorrect email');
       }

   } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).send(handleError(err));
   }
}

const logout = async (req, res, next) => {
    res.send('logout');
 }

 export { register, login, logout };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was also facing the same issue. Fixed by changing code at two places

1. On client side

```
    // added this in axios instance
    axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

2. On backend side

```
  const corsOptions = {
      origin: true, 
      credentials: true, 
  }; 
  app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36824106/express-doesnt-set-a-cookie) to know more.