# How can I access a cookie from an Express middleware when req.cookies returns an empty object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies

I am trying to validate a cookie using `cookie-parser` to check if the user is authenticated to access to restricted routes in my app. I am using NodeJS and Express for the server, and Sveltekit for the frontend.

I've set the cookie when creating the user, and it is saved correctly in the headers (as I can see it on the Request Headers from the network in the Dev Tools), but when I try to access to the cookie from my Express Middleware, it returns undefined, and `req.cookies` returns an empty object.

Here is how I set the cookie when the user is authenticated:

```
 // create jwt and cookie
const jwToken = jwt.sign({ id: user._id }, JWT_SECRET);
return res
        .cookie("authToken", jwToken, {
          httpOnly: true,
        })
        .status(200)
        .json({
          loggedIn: true,
          message: "Email verified successfully",
        });
```

Here is the middleware from which I am trying to access to the cookie:

```
export const isAuth = async (req, res, next) => {

  console.log("token value:", req.cookies?.authToken);
  next();
};
```

Here is my router:

```
router.get("/is-auth", isAuth, checkIsAuth);
```

I am using a different domain for frontend and backend, but the request it is accessing to the endpoint correctly (I'm in localhost), so I think is not a CORS issue.

I've tried adding options when setting up the cookie: `{ // secure: true, // sameSite: "none", // path: "/", httpOnly: true, }`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have imported `cookie-parser` and used in `app.use()`

```
const cokieParser = require("cookie-parser");

app.use(cokieParser());
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the answer here helps? [Express doesn't set a cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36824106/express-doesnt-set-a-cookie)

- If using fetch:

If you do not specify credentials: 'include' in fetch options, cookies are neither sent to server nor saved by a browser, although the server response sets cookies.

```
return fetch('/your/server_endpoint', {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'same-origin',
    redirect: 'follow',
    credentials: 'include', // Don't forget to specify this if you need cookies
    headers: headers,
    body: JSON.stringify({
        first_name: 'John',
        last_name: 'Doe'
    })
})
```

- If using axios:
  should set withCredentials to true

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

Comment: I am adding the credentials already. I believe, without the credentials, I would not be able to access to the endpoint.